# Why is this pdf file broken and how to fix it?

Tags: pdf

I'm considering the [following](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101015068578;view=1up;seq=319) page of a book. If it's being viewed in a web preview, it is displayed properly. If I download a pdf of this page, it seems to be blank. It only seems. The text can be selected and copied (in the Firefox preview and Evince (but not Atril))

While processing with pdf2djvu I get the following error

```
PDF syntax warning (97406879): Missing or invalid segmentation symbol in JPX stream
```

This problem makes the page unreadable. Is there any way to fix it?

/edit: I was suspecting a corrupt pdf since 2 separate viewers failed to read the page.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The JPX image is complete, and can be read with Photoshop. Your download may be damaged, or your toolchain may not be able to work with JPEG2000 images (i.e., a *regular* JPEG reader will report exactly that error).

Comment: Yep, the pdf readers seem not to handle JPEG2000 images. See the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Evince and the Firefox PDF preview seem not to handle JPEG2000 images properly. You can use `ghostscript` to fix the problematic page ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1845176))

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: ... or avoid that and directly use Adobe's own Acrobat Reader. (It's free!)

Comment: ...which closed-source, proprietary and, most important, no longer supported for Linux...!

Comment: Linux? First time you mention this. So there are no good PDF viewers left for Linux ... that's indeed a bad sign. Adobe supporting it used to be one of the firm's more endearing points.

Comment: Please report it on Evince's bugtracker on Launchpad, indicating the bug's severity. IIRC it's some kind of regression. But I didn't test all viewers, maybe a KDE one would work.

Comment: Besides, I don't see any problem here and we can neglect that jp2000. We have djvu, which is much more efficient: Size of the document 165 MB (JPEG PDF) > 106 MB (JPEG2000 PDF) > 66,8 MB (JPEG2000 DJVU) > 66,2 MB (JPEG DJVU)